# STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED with CallNtPowerInformation()

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to get the current processor speeds/throttlings through `CallNtPowerInformation()` with the `ProcessorInformation` input:

```
SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo;
GetSystemInfo( &systemInfo );

numProcessors = (unsigned char)systemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
powerInformations = new PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[numProcessors];
long status = CallNtPowerInformation( ProcessorInformation, NULL, 0, powerInformations, numProcessors*sizeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION) );
```

Unfortunately, `status` is always equal to `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.  I can't find any documentation on why this would be, can anyone point me to some reasons why I would not be able to get the current processor information?

This is running on Windows 8, on a Surface Pro (using Desktop APIs), and I've tried starting VS2012 with elevated permissions to no effect.

Comment: Have you tried using WMI to get the same information out?

Comment: No, can you point me to what that means?

Comment: WMI (Windows Management Interface/Instrumentation) lets you query information about the OS and the system. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You cannot use desktop api functions on a slate, your code runs in a sandbox that generates access denied errors when you try anyway.

Comment: @Hans: I should be able to run anything I want on a Surface Pro, right? I'm writing this code inside a component explicitly incompatible with windows store apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I run this code in a Console application, it works, but if I run it inside of a Metro application, it fails.  I will ask a new question on how to execute code like this inside of a windows store app.